# TabularInline for through Model not showing on Django 3

Tags: django, django-models

First off, I am using Django 3.2.9. Here are my models, pretty straightforward:

```
class AChallenge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class SubAdvanced(models.Model):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    challenges = models.ManyToManyField(
        AChallenge, related_name = 'challenge', through='SubAdvancedChallenge')

class SubAdvancedChallenge(models.Model):
    sub_advanced = models.ForeignKey(
        SubAdvanced, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(
        AChallenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    percentage = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])
```

Here is my admin :

```
class AChallengeAdmin(MyAppAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(AChallenge, AChallengeAdmin)

class SubAdvancedChallengeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SubAdvancedChallenge
    extra = 1

class SubAdvancedAdmin(MyAppAdmin):
    inlines = (SubAdvancedChallengeInline,)

admin.site.register(SubAdvanced, SubAdvancedAdmin)
```

According to [every single tutorial I see on the internet](https://medium.com/@aswinshenoy/django-admin-setting-up-many-to-many-relationships-with-intermediate-models-782895cb48b2), I should be getting a nice inline editor like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Despite all this, I am only getting this:

[image]

If I try to force the inclusion of the "challenges" field, like this:

```
class SubAdvancedAdmin(BelleEmpreinteAdmin):
    fields = ("name", "challenges")
    inlines = (SubAdvancedChallengeInline,)
```

I will get the following error:

```
(admin.E013) The value of 'fields' cannot include the ManyToManyField 'challenges', because that field manually specifies a relationship model.
```

The fact that my `TabularInline` simply does not appear definitely seems like a bug, but it seems too crazy that this slipped through the cracks for so long. Anybody else met this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as some may have guessed, and as I realized while re-reading my question, the issue was with permissions, since I am browsing my admin site as a non-superuser.

My modelAdmins are inherited from an override, that adds users with `is_staff` set to `True` into superadmin permissions, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyAppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def _allow(self, user):
        return user.is_staff or user.is_superuser

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return self._allow(request.user)
```

But I did not create such permissions for `TabularInline`! So doing this did the trick:

```
class MyAppTabularInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    def _allow(self, user):
        return user.is_staff or user.is_superuser

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self._allow(request.user)

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return self._allow(request.user)
```

I then use this as my `TabularInline` and voila:

```
class SubAdvancedChallengeInline(MyAppTabularInlineAdmin):
    model = SubAdvancedChallenge
    extra = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but what if you write it

```
@admin.register(SubAdvanced)
class SubAdvancedAdmin(BelleEmpreinteAdmin):
    inlines = (SubAdvancedChallengeInline,)
```

Comment: Isn't that basically what I'm doing with `admin.site.register(SubAdvanced, SubAdvancedAdmin)`?